# DQL wont accept date

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony, mariadb

I have this repository function ment to select all votes related to an image fitting within a specific date:

```
public function getTopNImages(int $n)
    {

        $date = date_format(new \DateTime('first day of this month'), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

        var_dump($date);

        $q2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('aliasi2')
            ->select('count(v.id)')
            ->innerJoin('aliasi2.votes', 'v')
            ->where('aliasi2 = i')
            ->andwhere("date_diff(v.date, $date) >= 0");

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->select(array(
                'i',
                '(' . $q2->getDQL() .') votes' 
            ))
            ->orderBy('votes', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($n)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

I'm using the date format same as the one in mysql, the `var_dump` outputs this:

> string(19) "2017-03-01 09:39:34"

But for some reason I'm getting this:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 137: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '-'

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to protect your date by simple quotes so the lexer failed at the first '-'.

See the problem here :

```
"date_diff(v.date, 2017-03-01 09:39:34) >= 0"
```

You need to do this :

```
"date_diff(v.date, '$date') >= 0"
```

Or even better use setParameter()

Comment: it gave me `1 parameters expected 0 set`

Comment: It's because setParameter() must be in the main query, not in the subquery :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
$q2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('aliasi2')
        ->select('count(v.id)')
        ->innerJoin('aliasi2.votes', 'v')
        ->where('aliasi2 = i')
        ->andwhere("date_diff(v.date, :date) >= 0")
        ->setParameter('date', $date);
```

Which just set the date parameter...